# iPhone how to suppress phone dialer screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am writing an application which dials a phone number using the "tel" protocol. While dialing the standard iPhone dialer screen pops up. Is there any means by which this screen can be suppressed? Or make this screen device orientation aware?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to surpress the screen, as that would make apps be able to make calls without the user even knowing it. Didn't check the docs on that, though.

As for the orientation, don't know for sure but I don't think so. But don't you use the phone in portrait when calling?

Comment: "don't you use the phone in portrait when calling?" for manual calls you do, but I guess if your app runs in landscape and is triggering a call it will be a bit jarring for the user to have the orientation flipped whilst dialing

Comment: Yeah, my application is in landscape mode, so I need the phone dialer too in the landscape mode. Can this be done?